# Get duration of encrypted video file

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, duration

When using the commands:

```
ffmpeg -i filename 2>&1 | grep Duration 
ffprobe filename -show_format -hide_banner
```

The duration and bit rate appears as N/A but the rest of the format is correct, I believe this is because the file is encrypted using Lynk. I am wondering if there is away around this issue to get the duration even with the file being encrypted?

And this is program related as I use this command in a php script.

Thanks

Here is the log

[image: Here is the log]

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan see above mate

Comment: If ffmpeg can decrypt it, then run `ffmpeg -i filename -an -f null - 2>&1 | grep time=`

Comment: Please do not post images with text. Post the text itself.